# Power outage during Bitcoin Core initial synchronization

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, synchronization

I had a power outage when I was half way through my Bitcoin Core initial synchronization. Is there a way to pick up where it left off or do I need to start over?

Comment: What happened when you started Bitcoin Core again? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: The first time it wanted me to install bitcoin core again. I rebooted and started it again, this time it picked back up and seemed to be ok but I haven't checked it since last night.